# `std::views::transform | std::views::filter` calls the transform function twice too many times

Tags: c++, c++20

Consider this toy example of `transform | filter` on a range

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>

struct X
{
  int fI = 1;
  int ToInt() const
  {
    std::cout << "ToInt called" << std::endl;
    return fI;
  }
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<X> v(3);

  std::cout << "start range" << std::endl;
  for (int i : v | std::views::transform(&X::ToInt)
     | std::views::filter([](int i) { return i % 2 == 1; }))
  {
    std::cout << "range iteration" << std::endl;
  }

  std::cout << "start loop" << std::endl;
  for (const X& x : v)
  {
    if (x.ToInt() % 2 == 1)
      std::cout << "loop iteration" << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

```
start range
ToInt called
ToInt called
range iteration
ToInt called
ToInt called
range iteration
ToInt called
ToInt called
range iteration
start loop
ToInt called
loop iteration
ToInt called
loop iteration
ToInt called
loop iteration
```

As we can see, `ToInt` is called twice too many times in the range version, compared to the loop version (tested under both g++ and Microsoft's compiler). Is there a way to write this range such that `ToInt` is called only 3 times? I am worried that if I stack up more transforms and filters, their predicates will be called way too many times.

Comment: @cigien Yes it is the same question, thanks. The answer is sad though, as we will always wonder if using loops instead of ranges would be faster.

Comment: Please avoid "wondering" about what will be faster, since you (as well as everyone else) is almost certain to get it wrong most of the time. The only way to know if something is faster is to measure its performance. If it turns out that loops are faster when you measure them, then use them.

Comment: @cigien That means double the work. First code the program with ranges, then recode it with loops and measure both. We cannot do that.

Comment: That's a decision you'll have to make for yourself. If measurements indicate that a particular instance of using views is worth optimizing, only then should you take the effort to try out a loop version (or vice-versa) and compare the difference. If doing that work is too much effort you could just go for whichever version you think/feel is going to be faster, but you'll still just be left wondering until you actually measure.